# Youtube API iframe doesn't work on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I made a React/Redux App that uses the Youtube API to play videos. It works perfectly in my localhost, but it fails in production.
This is my script:

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 2. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    window.player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'yy8NwjEtEkQ',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 3. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 4. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>`
```

Here is my code in GitHub: https://github.com/davisjr2000/lr-react

Comment: Can you explain what happens a bit more? Like, probably check your console?

Comment: There are no console/logs errors, the function doesn't load. It works sometimes, like 10% of the time.

Comment: Can you tell what part of the code is not functioning?

Comment: In development, this script transforms a div#player into a Iframe that plays a Youtube video. In production, it doesn't work, but I don't get any errors either. The new YT.Player is not functioning.

Comment: Is creation of iframe blocked on your production web site? See https://ziplineinteractive.com/blog/how-to-prevent-a-website-from-being-loaded-in-an-iframe/